# Adjustbox margin

Tags: tikz-pgf, adjustbox

I want to display a vertical line in the middle of my document. 
For creating the line I use tikz and for adjusting a margin I use adjustbox.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{noto-sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
lmargin=0mm,
rmargin=0mm,
tmargin=0mm,
bmargin=0mm,
}

\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage{adjustbox}


\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]

\adjustbox{margin*=0cm 1cm 1cm 0cm}{ 
    \fill[black] (current page.north) rectangle ([xshift=0.1cm]current page.south);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the margin is either applied to the bottom OR to the top. But not both.

Regards Andi

Comment: Does the margin mean that the line starts one cm below the top and ends one cm above the bottom? If so, just do `\draw[line width=1mm] ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north) -- ([yshift=1cm]current page.south);`.

Comment: @marmot Thank you very much! Thats exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Also, adding `\adjustbox` *inside* a `tikzpicture` does not work as indented. You need to apply it *around* it.

Comment: @marmot: Please post your comment as an answer, so that AndiLeni can accept it to conclude the question.

Comment: @MartinScharrer Done, thanks for pinging me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my above comment.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{noto-sans}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
a4paper,
lmargin=0mm,
rmargin=0mm,
tmargin=0mm,
bmargin=0mm,
}

\usepackage{showframe}


\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[line width=1mm] ([yshift=-1cm]current page.north) -- ([yshift=1cm]current page.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add the comment text into your answer (maybe modified a little), so that the answer is selfcontaining.

Answer (score 2):

I think this task is easier with `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic}

\AddToShipoutPicture{
    \thicklines
    \setlength\unitlength{1mm}
    \AtPageCenter{\line(0,1){138.5}}
    \AtPageCenter{\line(0,-1){138.5}}
    }

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}    
\null
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: magic number 138.5mm is half of A4 paper height (297mm) minus 1cm for top and bottom margins.